# How to share docker daemon with HyperV VM

Tags: docker, hyper-v

I have a rather unique usecase.
Our host hyperv server has docker installed.
He also has some of our development environments running as VM.

My question would be how can the HyperV VM use the docker daemon to create images and launch container.

Anybody any idea

Comment: You can configure the docker server to expose port TCP 2375, and interact with it that way.  For clients, tell the cmdline tool to interact with that server's hostname/ip with that port.

Comment: can i make docker desktop also connect to the docker daemon

Comment: can you point me to the commands i have to use to use docker daemon on the other host